# Using keystrokes to select DataGridView row

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

Hello I have a datagridview with many rows. I would like to be able to click on a cell and type some letters and have a matching row get selected (or scroll to it). I can sort out which column it is sorting to, but right now there is no 'search' capability.

When you open a Window's Explorer window and click on a file, you can start typing to have the selection move to the file/folder that matches your keystrokes.

Is this possible with the datagridview?

Comment: Can you just set the `Selected` property of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant was the [DataGridRow.IsSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.isselected) property. Since you said you know which rows contains your results, you can call [DataGridView.ClearSelection()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxdf3ekh.aspx) and then set the `IsSelected` property of the row that contains the data to true.

Comment: ah yes i was able to get it going using these functions. probably not the most efficient, but for me it rarely is. thanks though.